# Form Code Missing Something?

Tags: html, forms

First time posting here on Stackoverflow, can you guys tell me what's missing with this code? It's supposed to be a form but the "Submit" button does nothing. Thanks!

```
  <div class="container">
   <span class="reg"> <h1>Register Now</h1> </span>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="conent-part">
       <div class="form-body">
        <div class="fome-body">
          <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-part">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Your Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Your Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nominee's Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nominee's Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-part">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nominee's Sport">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Accomplishments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="custom_btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn2">Submit</button>
                </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: Your opening `<form>` tag is devoid of any attributes. The form does nothing because you haven't told it what to do.

Comment: Also fix your HTML, 5 elements of yours have the same id.

Comment: I'm stumped, lol. My brain hurts a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<div class="custom_btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn2">Submit</button>
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="custom_btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn2">Submit</button>
</div>
```

By just typing type=button you're just telling us that its a button without stating a function for it.The type="submit" will automatically submit the form to the specified URL.

Comment: I'll vote up both of you guys if I can but unfortunately I can't since I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button">
```

has no default behaviour, if you want to submit the form you'd just use `<button>` without the `type` attribute defined (`submit` is the default value).

[See the docs for more info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)